# Pass a condition from a string to numpy where

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have a series of conditions that can vary depending on the name of a selection. I would like to know if there is a way to construct the condition to python numpy where from a set of strings. Below there is an example program. What I would like is to be able get the same result in the two instances of `a[ind]`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10) 
ind = np.where((a>6) | (a<3))
print a[ind]

select = 'c'
if (select == 'c'):
    sel0 = '(a>6)'

sel = sel0 + ' | (a<3)'
print sel

ind = np.where(sel)
print a[ind]
```

Here is the output I get at the moment:

```
[0 1 2 7 8 9]
(a>6) | (a<3)
[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the literal `sel`:

```
ind = np.where(eval(sel))
print(a[ind])
# [0 1 2 7 8 9]
```

---

#### But why even use string literals?

```
select = 'c'
if select == 'c':
    sel0 = a>6

sel = sel0 | (a<3)
print(sel)

ind = np.where(sel)
print(a[ind])
# [0 1 2 7 8 9]
```

It doesn't actually matter on where the conditions are evaluated as long as it follows the same order of operations. Wherever you evaluate the conditions, `sel` will always be equal to:

```
[ True  True  True False False False False  True  True  True]
```

And with that boolean array, `where` will always produce the same output.